# Remove Map Node from JSON

Tags: json, dictionary

I am creating a JSON in Java:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    String json = null;
    Map<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> data2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data1.put("name", "f1");
    data1.put("key", "aa1");
    data1.put("value", "21");
    data2.put("name", "f2");
    data2.put("key", "aa1");
    data2.put("value", "22");

    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(data1);
    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(data2);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(json1);
    array.put(json2);
    JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        finalObject.put("DeltaRealTime", array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    json = new Gson().toJson(finalObject);
```

What I get is the following:

```
{
    "map": {
        "DeltaRealTime": {
            "myArrayList": [{
                "map": {
                    "name": "f1",
                    "value": "21",
                    "key": "aa1"
                }
            }, {
                "map": {
                    "name": "f2",
                    "value": "22",
                    "key": "aa1"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But I do not want to have all these extra "map" nodes. What I can I do to remove them? Or what I can I do that I do not have them in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what library and language you are programming with.

Comment: OK I added the imports. Also I am using: org.json-20120521.jar

Comment: did you ever manage to get a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply convert JSONObject to String you can use the toString() meethod. I did the same thing as you did without using the Gson Library and I didn't get any map node.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class checkTimeStamp {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> data2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data1.put("Hello", "abc");
    data1.put("Hello1", "abc");
    data1.put("Hello2", "abc");
    data2.put("Hello", "abc");
    data2.put("Hello1", "abc");
    data2.put("Hello2", "abc");
    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(data1);
    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(data2);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(json1);
    array.put(json2);
    JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();
    try{
        finalObj.put("RealTimeData", array);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String json = finalObj.toString();
    System.out.println(json);
}
}
```

And the Output was:

```
{"RealTimeData":[{"Hello1":"abc","Hello2":"abc","Hello":"abc"},{"Hello1":"abc","Hello2":"abc","Hello":"abc"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an Object to JSON string converter lib like Jackson. You can get a json str in three simple steps and dont have to create any JSON objects:

**Steps**

1. Create a POJO class
2. Populate the POJO object
3. Convert the object to a JSON string using the method as how below:

   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.writeValueAsString(FooPOJO);

Ref: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

My answer may help anyone in the future as none of the answers above worked for me. I just called `toMap()` on the JSONObject and all occurences of the `map` key were gone.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue, can you let me know how exactly you fixed this?

Comment: @calculus, I called a toMap() on the JSONObject then the map node disappeared

Answer (score 0):

you can try as:

String requestBody=data1.toString();
String requestBody=data2.toString();